# Not able to log in into Tomcat manager

Tags: java, tomcat

I don't have any credentials for my tomcat manager. Everything is commented. When I run http://localhost:8080/manager/html, it asks for username and password. When I try to login without them, it still doesn't work. I'm not able to edit the file too to uncomment.

Here is the tomcat-users.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='cp1252'?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
(the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
 -->
 <tomcat-users>
 <!--
NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
t o operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
 you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
  and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
  <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
-->
<!--
 <role rolename="tomcat"/>
 <role rolename="role1"/>
 <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
 <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
 <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
-->
```

I even don't see as Run as administrator to open in Brackets. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncomment the `user` and `role` entries in the said xml to enable a login user.

This entry should get you going-

`<role rolename="manager"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager"/>`

I think this goes without saying that you need to have `write` privileges on `Tomcat` home dir.

P.S. Don't forget to restart the server

Comment: I know to uncomment. But, I'm not able to save it after uncommenting

Comment: Try `sudo` if it's a *nix mahince. Eg. `sudo vim tomcat-users.xml`

Comment: I'm using windows. Sudo is used only for Linux flavors, right?

Comment: Yes. You need to have `write` access on the file

Comment: I'm not able to change any write access under security settings. Its in C drive. :(

Comment: Download `Tomcat` server again and place it under a directory where you have `write` privileges. Like *My Documents*